# Can you set Page Output Cache by an Individual user?

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I have a master page which has a rather simple menu system.  The menu items available are based on the logged on user.  However, the database calls to determine this logic are over a second which is probably too long for my liking.

Is there a way to wrap the Menu into a UserControl but along with having a duration to refresh but obviously also the output cache should be on a per user basis?

I know the other solution is to cache the data for each user and then rebuild but I thought the more efficent place to start would be Page Output cache.

Please note also this application does not user Session state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at `VaryByParam` method of Page Output Caching.

When your user logs in add a query string to your page something like `page.aspx?uid=x123`

then add the following to your page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10800" VaryByParam="uid" %>
```

This will make it per user cache.

**Do remember:**
Even if you put your user as a query string, still do the validation, that its the same user who logged in, to avoid users peeking into each other's view by simply changing the query string.

Comment: So to be clear...there will be a cached item per Param (User).  Or does the cache just clear and reset everytime a new user logs in?

Comment: New user login doesn't destroy VaryByParam caches. Its the Duration that destroys it. Once the duration is over its gone.